# Move sub SCNNode to rootNode while retaining position

Tags: ios8, scenekit, scnnode

I am having trouble retaining the position of a sub node removed and added to the *rootNode*. Both the parent node and sub node have a *pivot* translation, which I think is part of the problem. I have tried setting the *transform* property to the *worldtransform* property, then removing and reattaching the node to the root. But the position moves slightly. I have tried removing the pivot transform, getting the *worldtransform* adding to the root node and restoring the *pivot*. Sometimes I think I've resolved it, then a particular node will jump when reattached as a root node.

It seems the *pivot* of the sub node and parent node influences the *worldtransform*. So taking the parent node out of the equation seems to shift the final position.

Is there a method to adding a sub node to the root node, while maintaining its physical position/rotation.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

there is not API to do that. But SceneKit exposes conversion utilities such as `-[SCNNode convertTransform:toNode:]` and `-[SCNNode convertPosition:toNode:]`.

The following is probably what you want:

```
node.transform = [node.parentNode convertTranform:node.transform toNode:nil];
[node removeFromParentNode];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that only works if the parent node pivot is SCNMatrix4Identity. If the parent has a pivot translation, then the reattached node shifts position.

Comment: If node is inside multiple objects 

Root Node -> Child One - > Child 2 -> Node to be converted to ROOT  ?

Answer (score 1):

I also don't get why worldTransforms or worldPosition incorporates the pivot which is kind of insider info to the node.

Anyway, my solution:

```
MoveNode.transform = [newParentNode convertTransform:MoveNode.transform fromNode:[MoveNode parentNode]];
```